# format date select * perl

Tags: oracle, perl

I'd like to format all the dates from a `select * from table`, but I dont't know the columns of the table.
I'd like to format all the columns with datatype DATE to a specific format when I return the results.

I'm working on Oracle and perl scripts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = '<your date format>';
```

e.g.:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE              
---------------------
09/06/2016 09:33:38
```

Bear in mind that if you exclude the time portion (e.g. it's irrelevant for some columns as it's always set to midnight), then your output for those columns which do have a time portion will be misleading - e.g.:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE   
----------
09/06/2016
```

I'm a bit confused as to why you wouldn't know what columns you were dealing with, though. It's not that difficult to look in the database and obtain that information.

Comment: Well, the fields of the tabel could change inthe future, that's the reason I prefer to use 'select *'. I will test the proposed answer. Thanks

Comment: In general, `select *` in production code is bad. You haven't said what purpose your scripts have, so it may or may not make sense to use `select *`. Laziness in writing the scripts is, IMHO, not a good reason (not that I'm saying this is what is happening here; there isn't enough info to determine that!). And if the structure of the tables do change in the future, then your scripts should also change accordingly; after all, if they're part of the application process (e.g. reporting), then they should be treated in a similar way to the rest of the application code.

Comment: Well, it's a tool to copy some rows from a database tables to another, it's not a continuos process, it is run eventually.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, that's more understandable then *{:-) Is there any reason why you're not using the Oracle export/import or datapump tools to do the copying instead?

Comment: Well, we are developing a process to cutomize the export to make it easier for the users. It's used by final Users.